# Having problem in in logging in using RBAC

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router, rbac

So im implementing a rbac in my code so i use laravel and react for this project i'm having problem so for context my role_id has label of like this

[image: THis is the role_Id label i call for my backend]

now i implement it using a **RequireAuth.jsx** so it has this code

```
import { useLocation,Navigate, Outlet} from 'react-router-dom';
import useAuth from '../hooks/useAuth';

const RequireAuth = ({ allowedRoles }) => {
  const { auth } = useAuth();
  const location = useLocation();
  const userRole = auth?.role_id;

// Check if the user's role matches any of the allowed roles
const isAllowed = allowedRoles?.includes(userRole);

return (
    isAllowed ? (
        <Outlet />
    ) : (
        auth?.user ? (
            <Navigate to={{ pathname: '/unauthorized', state: { from: location } }} replace />
        ) : (
            <Navigate to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: location } }} replace />
        )
    )
);
}
export default RequireAuth;
```

and my app.jsx has the allowedRoles being use for calling the role_id this is my
**App.jsx**

```
function App() {

return (
<Routes>
  {/* Public Route */}
  <Route path="login" element={<Login/>}/>
  <Route path='*' element={<NotFound/>}/>
  <Route path='unauthorized' element={<Unauthorized/>}/>
  <Route path="create" element={<Create/>}/>
  <Route path="ask" element={<Ask/>}/>


  {/* Protected Route */}
  
  <Route element={<RequireAuth allowedRoles={[1]}/>}> 
    <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard/>}/>
    <Route  path="notification" element={<Notification/>}/>
    <Route path="user" element={<User/>}/>
    <Route path="scholar" element={<Scholar/>}/>
    <Route path="scholarship" element={<Scholarship/>}/>
    <Route path="submission" element={<Submission/>}/>
    <Route path="export" element={<Export/>}/>
    <Route path="school" element={<School/>}/>
    <Route path="view" element={<ViewSubmission/>}/>
  </Route> 

  {/* Manager Route */}
  <Route element={<RequireAuth allowedRoles={[2]}/>}>
    <Route path="scholar" element={<Scholar/>}/>
  </Route>

  {/* Scholar Route */}
  <Route element={<RequireAuth allowedRoles={[3]}/>}>
    <Route path="scholar-dashboard" element={<ScholarDashboard/>}/>
    <Route path="scholar-submission" element={<ScholarSubmission/>}/>
    <Route path="scholar-profile" element={<ScholarProfile/>}/>
  </Route>
</Routes>
)
}

export default App
```

so my main problem here is when i login using my admin account it works but when i try to login thru the manager and scholar it return unauthorized navigate from my requireauth.jsx and another goal is the scholar cant access some of the tabs of the admin

Comment: Is `auth.role_id` the "key", e.g. array index, or is it the value, e.g. one of `"Scholar Administrator"`, `"Scholar Manager"`, and `"Scholar"`? Seems the prop should be something like `allowedRoles={["Scholar Administrator"]}`. You have also some duplicate routes, e.g. `<Route path="scholar" element={<Scholar/>}/>`. Only one is valid. We may need more context and detail here.

Comment: auth.role_id is the value i use for getting the roles of every user i pass also allowedRoles={[2]}  like that but its now working the problem is in my onSubmitFunction  i forgot to change the navigate of every user its default to the scholar admin

Comment: I see, so you just had a logical bug where the login function was navigating to the incorrect route path? Why isn't it just navigating back to the referrer location that was passed in route state for the route the user was initially accessing, i.e. `location.state.from`, or a safe unprotected route as a fallback if they are only just authenticating?

Comment: yes that's what i mean thank you for the reply to my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just change my onsubmit with a navigate of every roles so i created a ternary operation to pass on it basing on the route they should have

```
const rolePath = role_id === 1  ? '/'  : role_id === 2 ? '/' : role_id === 3 ? '/scholar-dashboard' : '/login';

  // Navigate the user to the intended route (from variable contains the intended route)
  navigate(rolePath);
```